# How can i find day difference for same dates using mysql

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('2017-10-23 10:02:00','2017-10-22 10:02:00');
```

This will give me `1 day`, but what I need

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('2017-10-23 10:02:00','2017-10-23 09:02:00');
```

to get `1 day` as an output for same date but different time

I want to fetch day difference between 2 same dates.

Comment: You'll surely get difference between those two `datetimes` but its within `hours`, `minutes` & `seconds` because you were calculating for same day so it'll return you `0 days` always

Comment: yes i agree with your answer but requirement is to show in days so needed.

Comment: So for that you need to work around if you get `X days`  then you need to add it by `1` always

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use TIMESTAMPDIFF function to achieve the result:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,'2017-10-23 10:02:00','2017-10-23 09:02:00')/86400 AS diff;
```

Comment: but this won't give in days.

Comment: @harish_sng well you could always divide your result 86400 and get result in days

Comment: Exactly.. Difference in his example is 1 hour which is 0.0417 days. You cant get 'non-decimal' result if you are looking for a difference in the same day..in days.